# Rails 4: Session Expiry?

Tags: session, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4

I just made the switch from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4. I'm trying to make sure I'm as up-to-speed as possible on security issues, and I'm concerned about sessions right now. It looks like Rails 4 has moved away from supporting really anything EXCEPT cookie-based sessions, but it sounds like it's not possible to prevent cookie-based sessions from living forever. I've been reading several articles, but this one is the most official: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-expiry . Notice how they point out that this is an issue for cookie-based sessions, then they give a fix for it for database-based sessions (which are now deprecated, apparently).

I'm really confused. I want to be able to prevent an attacker from getting a cookie that gives him permanent access to my login-protected site. Obviously I can set :expire_after in initializers/session_store.rb, but unless I'm wrong that simply sets the expiration of the cookie which is client-side and easily altered by an attacker so the session can live forever. Of course I can make things better by forcing SSL, using secure cookies, and forcing HTTP only, but this will never be a complete defence until I can enforce session expiry.

How can I solve this problem when Rails is deprecating the only ways to have server-side sessions?

I know active record sessions has been moved into a gem and is still available, but the fact remains that it has been deprecated. A solution should be possible without introducing more dependencies, or at the very least without using deprecated features.

Comment: It's a very valid question - and Rails guides are... well.. what they are. I would be glad knowing a good answer to your question because I totally understand why you got confused by what is still there, even in the latest "edge" ..

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Rails has "tamper-proof" session cookies. To prevent session hash tampering, a digest is calculated from the session with a server-side secret and inserted into the end of the cookie. Just make sure you have a long secret. If you want to periodically reset all user sessions change your secret.

To answer your question, if you want to add an extra time-out to the session data you could do:

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
session[:expires_at] = Time.current + 24.hours
```

Then, when authenticating users, do:

```
if session[:expires_at] < Time.current
  # sign out user
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that this solution won't work as-is by default with Rails 4.1 and later. The cookie serializer now defaults to JSON so Time objects are stored as strings.

Comment: `session[:expires_at].to_time < Time.current` will work

Comment: Probably the more typical use is to expire the session after a preselected period of inactivity rather than suddenly out of nowhere because the original expiration time passed. But this doesn't seem to be (explicitly) covering such use-case. Putting the second line as `before_action` line in Application Controller rather than as part of the login action would address the problem.

Answer (score 41):

Actually rails inherits from `Rack::Session::Cookie`.
So you can configure `expire_after` parameter in your `session_store.rb`.

```
Sqore::Application.config.session_store(
  :cookie_store,
  key: '_name_session',
  expire_after: 24.hours
)
```

Comment: No, the poster explicitly said he didn't want to do this because it can be tampered with on the client side.

Comment: Great answer.  Documentation is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html

Comment: Add `domain: :all` if you have subdomains.

Comment: You can just use `Rails.application.config.session_store` if you want to make a bit more generic

Answer (score 3):

add this to your application controller:

```
before_filter :session_expires, :except => [:login, :logout]
before_filter :update_session_time, :except => [:login, :logout]

def session_expires
  @time_left = (session[:expires_at] - Time.now).to_i 
  unless @time_left > 0
    reset_session
    flash[:error] = 'Lorem Ipsum.'
    redirect_to :controller => 'foo', :action => 'bar'
  end
end

def update_session_time
  session[:expires_at] = 60.minutes.from_now
end
```