# Rails/Devise - how to logout a user after an `x` minutes of inactivity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a system which contains many roles and one of the roles is `ADMIN` which can access critical part of the system, I want to limit the user's session which when he/she don't interact with the system for certain period of time, its session gets expires and the next time he/she should log in again, How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Devise has a [timeoutable](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Timeoutable) module that you can use.

In your `User` model you would include `:timeoutable` with your `devise` models and in the `devise.rb` initializer you would configure it comparable to:

```
  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  config.timeout_in = ENV['YOUR_TIME'].to_i.minutes
```

If you want to be more flexible with your user types you can add a method something like this for your `User` model:

```
def timeout_in
  if self.type == 'Admin'
    45.minutes
  else
    60.minutes
  end
end
```

That would be used instead of setting `timeout_in` in your initializer.

Comment: Or `ENV.fetch('YOUR_TIME', 5).to_i.minutes` if you want a default value instead of getting a cryptic NoMethodErrror

Comment: Nice approach, but all my roles are summed up by just a `User` model, with different `type_id`; Although I have come up with the other solution [`gem 'activerecord-session_store'`](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) to timeout the user session, but to accept your answer is there any way to make your solution dynamic only for different user types?

Comment: @dariush I updated the answer to hopefully answer your question in full

Comment: @dariush please see the [`timedout?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Timeoutable#timedout%3F-instance_method) method in the fine manual.

Comment: @dariush it actually does answer your question, "Rails/Devise - how to logout a user after an `x` minutes of inactivity?"

Comment: @dariush This only signs sessions out after a period of inactivity. See this comment from `timeoutable.rb`

"Each time a record is set we check whether its session has already timed out or not, **based on last request time**. If so, the record is logged out and redirected to the sign in page. Also, each time the request comes and the record is set, we set the last request time inside its scoped session to verify timeout in the following request."

[devise/timoutable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My first response was similar to the first answer in the thread below, but the second answer in that thread might be a better fit. Since it works directly with the session_store.

Here's a useful StackOverflow link that can provide extra info: [Rails 4: Session Expiry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480487/rails-4-session-expiry)

This documentation has some info on the methods available for session manipulation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html